# Problema ao enviar dados de uma aplicação console para WebService

Tags: c#, web-service, console-application

Possuo uma aplicação console que recebe dados de um dispositivo móvel, estou tentando enviar estes dados para um webservice fazer o tratamento dos dados e preenchê-los no banco de dados.

Estou tentando desta forma:

```
public static async Task PostWS(string dado)
{
    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        var url = @"rota do método no webservice";
        var jsonString = @"{'Packet': '" + dado+"'}";
        var content = new StringContent(jsonString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        content.Headers.Clear();
        content.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        HttpResponseMessage resposta = httpClient.PostAsync(url, content).Result;
        if (resposta.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            HttpContent conteudo = resposta.Content;
            string resultado = conteudo.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine("ok");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("erro");
        }
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
 }
```

Eu consigo acessar o método do meu webservice o problema é que aparentemente não estou conseguindo enviar os dados corretamente.

Método do WebService que estou tentando acessar:

```
[HttpPost]
        [Route("teste")]
        public HttpResponseMessage testando(Device device)
        {
            string rout = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LogFile"];
            try
            {
                System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@rout, device.Packet);
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Não consigo escrever os dados no arquivo de texto. OBS: Não da erros.

Onde estou errando ?

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: *"ele não acessa o método do meu webservice"* pode explicar isso melhor? dá erro, qual o erro? é um post mesmo? o ContentType  está correto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fiz sem testar, pode ser necessários pequenos ajustes, creio que pelo HttpClient seja a melhor forma, mais fácil.

```
using System;

using System.Net.Http;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            var url = @"https://seusite.com";
            var jsonString = @"{'parametro': 'valor'}";
            var content = new StringContent(jsonString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            content.Headers.Clear();
            content.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient.PostAsync(url, content).Result;
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                HttpContent conteudo = resposta.Content;
                string resultado = await conteudo.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Console.WriteLine("ok");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("erro");
            }
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
} 
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. O método funcionou comigo, mas tive que comentar as linhas "content.Headers.Clear();" e "content.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");", fora isso deu tudo certo. Obrigado mais uma vez :)

Comment: eu coloquei o x-www-form-urlencoded, pq vi na sua pergunta e ai o padrão é limpar o header e depois adicionar os que vc quer, no caso era o x-www-form-urlencoded

Answer (score 0):

Olá, segue um exemplo para você:

```
[WebMethod]
public bool IsUserExist(string userName) {
    if (userName == "Teste")
     return true;
    else
     return false;
}

protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("userName=" + TextBox1.Text);

    System.Net.WebRequest request = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create("http://localhost/samples/MyService.asmx/IsUserExist");

    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentLength = data.Length;
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

    System.IO.Stream str = request.GetRequestStream();
    str.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    str.Flush();
    System.Net.WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
    System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
    string result = reader.ReadToEnd();

    TextBox2.Text = result;
}
```

Espero que ajude :)

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, contudo estou com algumas duvidas. Qual é a utilidade dos dois parâmetros do método Button2_Click ? já que você não esta utilizando eles dentro do método. A outra duvida é na linha "byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("userName=" + TextBox1.Text);", qual é o motivo de "userName=" ? desde já agradeço.

Comment: o código fornecido pelo Dalton é windows form, precisa adapta-lo